# How to write to StdIn of current process?

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application

I'm trying to do the following to prevent my console app do be stuck on `Console.ReadLine()` during termination.

```
await Process.GetCurrentProcess().StandardInput.WriteLineAsync();
```

but I'm getting the `InvalidOperationException` `StandardIn is not redirected.`

The attempt based on John's comment also fails with an exception `Stream was not writable`:

```
using (var stdInStream = Console.OpenStandardInput())
using (var stdInWriter = new StreamWriter(stdInStream))
    await stdInWriter.WriteLineAsync();
```

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: Not `Console.OpenStandardInput()` or `Console.SetIn(textReader)`?

Comment: Perhaps you need a [timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57615/how-to-add-a-timeout-to-console-readline)?

Comment: @John Attempting to write to the stream returned by `Console.OpenStandardInput()` throws an exception saying `Stream was not writable.`. The code handing the console is not something I can easily change, I intentionally did not ask how to augment the ReadLine part.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast Did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10208589) in particular not work?

Answer (score 0):

On windows, Console.[ReadLine](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Console/src/System/ConsolePal.Windows.cs#L1167) ends up blocking on a Kernel32 [ReadLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile) call. While there might be a way to interrupt that call and cause it to return, writing to your own input doesn't seem like the right answer.

You might be able to call [CancelSynchronousIo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/cancelsynchronousio-func), or just [exit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.exit?view=netcore-3.1) your own process. Neither of which is ideal.

Edit; a potentially related [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1606)