# How to unit test code that requires user input c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, integration-testing

its my first time doing unit tests/integration tests and I have a question. So I started doing unit tests for my code, but I have a method, which is actually the logic of the whole application, where multiple methods are called, and user input is required. How can I test that method? Here is the method:

```
  public async Task RunAsync()
    {
      
        var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var playAgain = 'y';

        do
        {
            var attempts = 1;
            var foundNumber = false;
            while (attempts < 10 && foundNumber == false)
            {
                try
                {
                    var inputNumber = int.Parse(GetInput());

                    if (inputNumber == _randomNumber)
                    {
                        foundNumber = true;
                        OnSuccesfulGuess(watch, attempts);

                    }
                    else if (attempts < 10)
                    {
                        OnWrongGuessWithinAttempts(inputNumber);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Oops, maybe next time.");                      
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number");
                }

                attempts++;
            }

            playAgain = PlayAgain(playAgain);
            _randomNumber = await GetRandomNumber(1, 100);
            Log.Information("User wants to play again");
        }
        while (playAgain == 'y' || playAgain == 'Y');
    }
```

This is the method where i run in my Program class in order to start the application.

Comment: [This might help](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ploeh/2006/10/21/console-unit-testing/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is essentially untestable.

The method does too much work. It should be splitted into several smaller ones that can be tested separately.

You should get rid of static methods. Because you can't get them fake.

Getting data over the network (I see using WebSocket), as well as from the database or file system, should be brought out. You should pass ready-made data to this method.

---

Here is the modified code, broken down into small methods. Logging and events are removed from the code so as not to complicate the explanation.

```
public class App
{
    private readonly Random _random = new Random();

    private Task<int> GetRandomNumber(int min, int max)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(_random.Next(min, max));
    }

    internal int GetInput()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please guess a number between 1 and 100");
        int value;

        while (true)
        {
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            bool result = int.TryParse(input, out value);

            if (!result)
                Console.WriteLine("Not a number");
            else if (value < 1 || value > 100)
                Console.WriteLine("Must be between 1 and 100");
            else
                break;
        }
        return value;
    }

    internal bool PlayAgain()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Do you want to play again?");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        return input == "Y" || input == "y";
    }

    internal void Guessing(int randomNumber)
    {
        int attempts = 1;
        while (attempts < 10)
        {
            var inputNumber = GetInput();
            // logging
            if (inputNumber == randomNumber)
            {
                // OnSuccesfulGuess
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                // OnWrongGuessWithinAttempts
            }
            attempts++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Oops, maybe next time.");
        // logging
    }

    public async Task RunAsync()
    {
        do
        {
            int randomNumber = await GetRandomNumber(1, 100);
            Guessing(randomNumber);
        }
        while (PlayAgain());
    }
}
```

Now we have the ability to test individual methods.
I use MSTest.

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow("Y")]
[DataRow("y")]
public void PlayAgain_InputY_ReturnsTrue(string value)
{
    using (var reader = new StringReader(value))
    {
        Console.SetIn(reader);
        var app = new App();

        bool result = app.PlayAgain();

        Assert.IsTrue(result);
    }
}

[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow("N")]
[DataRow("boo")]
[DataRow("")]
public void PlayAgain_InputNotY_ReturnsFalse(string value)
{
    using (var reader = new StringReader(value))
    {
        Console.SetIn(reader);
        var app = new App();

        bool result = app.PlayAgain();

        Assert.IsFalse(result);
    }
}
```

We do the same with the other methods.

---

Here are the tests for the `GetInput` method.

Since there is a loop inside that runs indefinitely when incorrect values are entered, we must interrupt it by entering the correct value. This is done by passing two values via a line feed: `"0\n50"`. Entering an incorrect value is a test of the output string, then interrupting the loop with the correct value.

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow("1")]
[DataRow("50")]
[DataRow("100")]
public void GetInput_InputCorrectString_ReturnsNumber(string value)
{
    using (var reader = new StringReader(value))
    {
        Console.SetIn(reader);
        var app = new App();

        int actual = app.GetInput();
        int expected = int.Parse(value);

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
}

[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow("0\n50")]
[DataRow("101\n50")]
public void GetInput_InputSmallerOrGreaterValue_WritesMessage(string value)
{
    using (var reader = new StringReader(value))
    using (var writer = new StringWriter())
    {
        Console.SetIn(reader);
        Console.SetOut(writer);
        var app = new App();

        _ = app.GetInput();

        string actualMessage = writer.ToString();
        string expectedMessage = "Must be between 1 and 100";

        Assert.IsTrue(actualMessage.Contains(expectedMessage));
    }
}

[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow("x\n50")]
[DataRow("qwerty\n50")]
public void GetInput_InputNotNumber_WritesMessage(string value)
{
    using (var reader = new StringReader(value))
    using (var writer = new StringWriter())
    {
        Console.SetIn(reader);
        Console.SetOut(writer);
        var app = new App();

        _ = app.GetInput();

        string actualMessage = writer.ToString();
        string expectedMessage = "Not a number";

        Assert.IsTrue(actualMessage.Contains(expectedMessage));
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much!! can you explain to me why methods are internal and not public?

Comment: @Josh - They are made so for [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) purposes. To test these methods, use [InternalsVisibleToAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute)

Answer (score 0):

Normally the unit testing methods are made regarding the different results that may return. You can create an interface to handle this method and communicate giving values depending of the output expected (Mocking). Check this post maybe would help!:
[How do I apply unit testing to C# function which requires user input dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10181421/how-do-i-apply-unit-testing-to-c-sharp-function-which-requires-user-input-dynami)