# Unit Testing a C# function that uses Console.ReadLine()

Tags: c#, unit-testing, console, console-application

The function below uses `TryParse()` to parse a `Console.Readline()` value

```
public uint parse_input(string input)
{
    uint parseNumber;

    while (!uint.TryParse(input, out parseNumber))
    {
        Console.Write("The value must be of integer type, please try again: ");
    }

    return parseNumber;
}
```

where `input` is `string input = Console.ReadLine();` defined in another method.

If I enter an erroneous value, I get stuck in a loop as the input value is set.

However, if I replace `input` with `Console.ReadLine()`:

```
while (!uint.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out parseNumber))
{
    Console.Write("The value must be of integer type, please try again: ");
}
```

The function works, as `input returned` is replaced with `System.Console.ReadLine` returned.

I want to be able to unit test this function, so ideally, I would like how I initially defined it to work.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# unit test for a method which calls Console.ReadLine()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161341/c-sharp-unit-test-for-a-method-which-calls-console-readline)

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate the input/output logic from the logic you want to test (since you do not want to test the .net framework code (that is not *your* job)). But that leaves us with the question: what is that you really want to test here? Is it the "uint.TryParse(input, out parseNumber)" logic?

So create a class that does the input/output stuff and make it expose a nice interface that you can depend on for your logic class, then you can unit test it.