# How do I unit test a C# function when that function must write to stdout

Tags: c#, stdout, visual-studio-2019, stdin, mstest

I have a function whose specification calls for it to write to stdout.  When I test, stdout is MIA and I can't find it.  I need to catch it so I can assert expected responses.  The method will be called by a command pipeline.

In addition, I will be writing some pipeline functions:  ==stdin==> *method* ==stdout==>.  That means my unit tests need to push test data into stdin.

I am planning the test scenario before writing the methods and not finding a lot of recent information.  I am hoping that MSTest might have some helper methods for this.  If not, I could use some guidance regarding how I might go about writing my own.

Comment: make the function itself just consume generic streams - then you can test it - and write a wrapping function that pipes STDIO into this function.

Comment: Dotnet also provides the ability to set the input and output of Console to any TextWriter/TextReader. See [Console.SetOut](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.setout?view=netcore-3.1) and [Console.SetIn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.setin?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# unit test for a method which calls Console.ReadLine()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161341/c-sharp-unit-test-for-a-method-which-calls-console-readline)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest passing in a `TextReader` and a `TextWriter`, maybe as optional parameters. You can then read from the reader and write to the writer. Then either the caller passes in `Console.Out` and `Console.In`, or you can do it in the method:

```cs
public void Foo(TextReader reader = null, TextWriter writer = null)
{
    reader = reader ?? Console.In;
    writer = writer ?? Console.Out;
    // Read and write
}
```

(Or use a parameterless overload that calls an overload with two required parameters.)

In your unit tests, use a `StringReader` and a `StringWriter`.

If you can *required* the caller to pass in the reader and the writer, it would allow you to avoid coupling your code tightly to the console, leading to generally cleaner code - I can imagine a whole series of methods all of which accept a reader/writer (or use fields for them) so that only the very top level code "knows" that it's dealing with the console.

Comment: Thanks to lockdown, here's the master himself.

Comment: Just what I am looking for.  Cheers!